# Validator error http POST response in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I dont know why i am getting a validator error response. I have tried to debug as much as possible but i cant see to find where the problem is. I have used the exact names i have used in my schema but still im getting the error in both postman and rest client
My server.js looks like this:

```
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const dotenv= require('dotenv')
const routesUrls=require('./routes/routes')
const cors = require('cors')
 
dotenv.config()
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS, () =>console.log("Database Connected"))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use('/app', routesUrls)
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("server is up and running"))
```

My routes.js

````
const router = express.Router()
const signupTemplateCopy = require('../models/SignUpModels')

router.post('/signup/', (request,response) =>{
const SignedupUser =  new signupTemplateCopy({
            fullname:request.body.fullname,
            username:request.body.username,
            email:request.body.email,
            password:request.body.password   
})

        SignedupUser.save().then(data =>{
        response.json(data)})
        .catch(error =>{
            response.json(error)
        })
})
module.exports = router ```

The Schema looks like this

```const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const signupTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({

    fullname:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true

    },
    password:{ 
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('mytable', signupTemplate)
````

The error

````
  "errors": {
    "fullname": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `fullname` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `fullname` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "fullname"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "fullname"
    },
    "username": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `username` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `username` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "username"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "username"
    },
    "email": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `email` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `email` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "email"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "email"
    },
    "password": {
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "message": "Path `password` is required.",
      "properties": {
        "message": "Path `password` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "password"
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "password"
    }
  },```
  "_message": "mytable validation failed",
  "message": "mytable validation failed: fullname: Path `fullname` is required., username: Path `username` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required."
}
````

Comment: how do you test your `API`? In what format are you trying to send your data?

Comment: it seems ur not putting in the required data

Comment: In Json.. What is the required data?

Answer (score 1):

make sure u have used the exact names in the POSTMANT and in the route.js
check the caps that was my issue

```
const router = express.Router();
const signUpTemplateCopy = require("../models/signupmodels");

router.post("/signup", (request, response) => {
 const signedUpUser = new signUpTemplateCopy({
   fullName: request.body.fullName,
   userName: request.body.userName,
   Email: request.body.Email,
   password: request.body.password,
 });
 signedUpUser.save().then((data) => {
   response.json(data).catch((error) => {
     response.json(error);
   });
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/signup/', (request,response) => {
const { fullname, username, email, password } = request.body
const SignedupUser =  new signupTemplateCopy()

SignedupUser.fullname = fullname;
SignedupUser.username = username;
SignedupUser.email = email;
SignedupUser.password = password;

SignedupUser.save()
.then(data => {
    response.json(data)
})
.catch(error => {
        response.json(error)
}) )}
```

You could give this a try.. I am fairly new to mongoDb, express, nodeJs, but I think a good practise is to put these kind of functions in a controller file.

Also, if using postman, make sure you set the headers, Content-Type -> Application/JSON. And that your raw body to send shoud look something like this...

```
{ "fullname": "John Doe", "username": "johndoe123", "email": "johndoe@gmail.com", "password": "123456 }
```